# Format Timestamp on Google Apps Script HTML Print

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, datetime-format

I haven't been able to figure out how to properly set a timestamp format for the output result of the script.

The script I've got pulls data from a Google Sheet, checks that the user viewing the HTML page is on the sheet, and returns only those values that match the signed in user's email (allowing them to view only their records). The script then prints out the matching records on an HTML page.

The problem is the timestamp column and it's formatting.

The values stored in the GS is the timestamp of when the entry was submitted, and is:

```
MM/DD/YYY HH:MM:SS.
```

When the script runs, the HTML output format of the timestamp column is the default:

```
Fri Dec 09 2022 15:16:47 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
```

I would like to keep the formatting as it's stored in the GS. I have tried multiple things here, but none seem to work.

This is the section of my script that pulls the sheet data and sends it to the Index.html page as a table:

```
function getData() {
  var sheetName = dataSheet;
  var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var values = activeSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var header = values[0];
  var emailIndex = header.indexOf(emailHeader);
  var userData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][emailIndex] == activeUser) {
      userData.push(values[i]);
    }
  }
  if (userData.length > 0) {
    var tableStart = '\n<table class="table table-hover table-sm">';
    var tableHead = '\n<thead>\n<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < header.length; j++) {
      tableHead = tableHead + '\n<th>' + header[j] + '</th>';
    }
    tableHead = tableHead + '\n</tr>\n</thead>';
    var tableBody = '\n<tbody>';
    for (var k = 0; k < userData.length; k++) {
      tableBody = tableBody + '\n<tr>';
      for (var l = 0; l < userData[0].length; l++) {
        tableBody = tableBody + '\n<td>' + userData[k][l] + '</td>';
      }
      tableBody = tableBody + '\n</tr>\n';
    }
    var tableEnd = '</tbody>\n</table>';
    var tableHtml = tableStart + tableHead + tableBody + tableEnd;
    return tableHtml;
  } else {
    return '<table class="table"><tbody><tr><td>No data found.</td></tr></tbody></table>';
  }
}
```

This is from the HTML page:

```html
<script>
        window.onload = function() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(user) {
                document.getElementById("currentUser").innerHTML = 'Hello ' + user + ", Here is your training history:";
            }).currentUser();

            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(userData) {
                document.getElementById("dataTable").innerHTML = userData;
            }).getData();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h4><br /></h4>
                <h4 id='currentUser'></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div id='dataTable'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: In your situation, when `var values = activeSheet.getDataRange().getValues();` is modified to `var values = activeSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();`, is that your expected values?

Comment: Son of a gun - I feel dumb. Yes, @Tanaike that does exactly what I need it to - thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.